# What are the Pros and Cons when using remote janusgraph connection over embedded?

Tags: java, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using embedded janusgraph in my java backend my code depends on janusgraph instanciated from `graph = JanusGraphFactory.open(conf)`

AFAIK this connects to Cassandra and elastic search directly and run the janusgraph processor in my backend application JVM. But if I want to scale janusgraph I need to run separate janusgraph servers on a cluster and need to connect to these servers as the client from my backend.

According to [remote janusgraph example on github](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-examples/example-remotegraph/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/RemoteGraphApp.java) this is accomplished using instantiating an EmptyGraph `graph = EmptyGraph.instance();` which is not instance of JanusGraph but of  `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.empty.EmptyGraph;`.

I can understand from the example above that I can only use gremlin queries by submitting them to janusgraph server, but I will not be able to use the management APIs directly unless submitting the code as a string to the server.

Finally, I can understand that it is better for scalability to run janusgraph server separately but I will lose the direct access in my code to janusgraph apis so I want to know if something I miss understand and  **what are the pros and cons in remote deployment approach and what I will lose against embedded approach?**

**Edit:**

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46985897/6522738)  *correct it if wrong*:

Pros/Cons of connecting to the remote gremlin server

Pros

- The server has much more control and all the queries are centralized.
- Since every one is running traversal/queries via the remote gremlin server, all are transactionally protected. The remote gremlin server runs your traversal/queries by default in a transaction.
- Central strategy management
- Central schema management

Cons

- Tough to do a manual transaction management
- You have to use groovy script as string and send it to remove (Cluster submit) for transactional execution of your code.

Comment: Hi, do you have any example of how to do transaction management with remote janusGraph

Answer (score 0):

Whatever Pros, Cons listed above are correct, along with that I will list out my learnings:

With the **gremlin server** approach, as a user, the architecture will look like a web server(*additional cost*) which is contacting the storage system. The upscale/downscale of these gremlin servers has to be handled manually based on the load, else it will become bottleneck of the entire system.

In **embedded mode**, you have a storage system (say Cassandra) and another one that does interact with this via tinker pop gremlin. With this, you don't have to maintain gremlin servers, it just your program/client is interacting with the storage server.

Consider data loading via Apache Spark, once you run job with more executors the gremlin server should be capable enough to handle loads.