# How can I get the JanusGraph instance in my java code?

Tags: java, connection, janusgraph

I am having trouble accessing a JanusGraph instance. The [documents](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/connecting-via-java.html) show sample code such as the following:

```
Graph graph = EmptyGraph.instance();
GraphTraversalSource g =
    graph.traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
```

and it works, but what I want is to get a JanusGraph instance, because almost all the examples given on the internet are based on JanusGraph instance, including the official examples and the bulk import utils, e.g.,

- https://github.com/IBM/janusgraph-utils
- https://github.com/FSixteen/janusgraph-utils

so I found [another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673861/how-can-i-remotely-connect-to-a-janusgraph-server) about it. I then tried the following:

```
GraphTraversalSource g = 
    JanusGraphFactory.open("inmemory").traversal().withRemote(config);
```

but when i do this, the procedures end up with:

```
ClassNotFindException: OptionSteps.class
```

So I wonder, how can I get the JanusGraph instance in my Java code? The code is running on Windows, and the JanusGraph is running on a Linux server—does it matter？ Do I have to run them together to find the `OptionSteps` class?

Comment: Thank you for you help! And I thought there might be something wrong with the dependence org.janusgraph.janusgraph-all, version 0.3.2.This dependence does not provide a class OptionalSteps. The Exception is ClassNotDefineError,not ClassNotFindException.When I change to the version 0.2.0, my code works. so,the JanusGraph instance is provided for the JanusGraph embeded mode and the inmemory mode？

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the dependencies, the correct artifact is `janusgraph-core` and you can see an [example usage](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.3.2/janusgraph-examples/example-common/pom.xml#L15-L17) in the JanusGraph project itself.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency is also mentioned in [Connecting from Java](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/connecting-via-java.html) in the JanusGraph docs.